# What does the third parameter in CONVERT() do?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

**Query**

Get the Joining year,Joining Month and Joining Date from employee table

This is my query which I have to perform. For this I write the following script:

```
select 
    SUBSTRING (convert(varchar,joining_date,103),7,4) , 
    SUBSTRING (convert(varchar,joining_date,100),1,3) , 
    SUBSTRING (convert(varchar,joining_date,100),5,2) 
from 
    EMPLOYEE
```

The result is: http://d.pr/i/vObI

But when I changed `convert(varchar,joining_date,100)` to `convert(varchar,joining_date,101)`

Result is like this: http://d.pr/i/G5fZ

Can anyone please explain what this parameter means?

Comment: If you google "*sql server convert*", the first three entries explain this in massive detail.

Comment: Microsoft has thoughtfully provided [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928(v=sql.105).aspx) to explain precisely what `CONVERT` - and every other [built-in function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174318(v=sql.105).aspx) - does, including what each parameter means.

Answer (score 0):

There are several different ways that you can format date using `convert(varchar...`.  These are well documented on the [MSDN site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) or [different sites online](http://anubhavg.wordpress.com/2009/06/11/how-to-format-datetime-date-in-sql-server-2005/).

Using `convert(varchar..., date, 100)` places the date in the format:

```
mon dd yyyy hh:mmAM (or PM)
May 10 2013 12:55PM
```

Using `convert(varchar...date, 101)` puts the date in the format:

```
mm/dd/yyyy
05/10/2013
```

See [Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/13540)

My suggestion would be whenever you implement these conversions, be sure to give a length on the `varchar(10)`, etc.

Based on what it looks like you are returning, you can eliminate some of the `convert`/`substring` statements that you are using and implement some other functions to get the same result:

```
select year(joining_date) as [year] , 
  convert(varchar(3),joining_date,100) as [month] , 
  day(joining_date) as [day]
from EMPLOYEE
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a better approach to split and get datetime parts using DATEPART:

```
  select DATEPART(YEAR, [joining_date]), 
  DATEPART(MONTH, [joining_date]), 
  DATEPART(DAY, [joining_date]) from EMPLOYEE
```

or if you are interested for example in names use DATENAME:

```
 select DATEPART(YEAR, [joining_date]), 
 DATENAME(MONTH, [joining_date]), 
 DATEPART(DAY, [joining_date]) from EMPLOYEE
```

However according to MSDN for DATENAME: "The return value depends on the language environment set by using SET LANGUAGE".

Regarding your initial question - these parameters are basically styles or I would call them Regional specific codes as described here, and you can just run the different queries against the DB and you will see the strings returned - and you will figure why you get unexpected results. For more infos refer to [MSDN: CAST and CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)